# Drop behavior in SQL DROP VIEW statement

Tags: sql, sql-drop

Is the Statement:

```
DROP VIEW <view-name>
```

a valid sql92 syntax? In some Databases (e.g Postgres, Redshift) there is the option to explicitly define a drop behavior

```
DROP VIEW <view-name> [RESTRICT|CASCADE]
```

While for others it is an obligatory (e.g Netteza)

```
DROP VIEW <view-name> {RESTRICT|CASCADE}
```

or simply unsupported in the syntax (e.g Transact-sql).

What does the sql92 standard state about drop view syntax regarding drop behavior?
I didn't find any mention to drop behavior in the sql92 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `RESTRICT` and `CASCADE` are mentioned in the ANSI-92 standard as `<drop behavior>` qualifiers in section 11.20

> If RESTRICT is specified, then V shall not be referenced in
>               the  of any view descriptor or the  of any assertion descriptor or constraint descriptor
>
> Note: If CASCADE is specified, then any such dependent object
>               will be dropped by the execution of the  spec-
>               ified in the General Rules of this Subclause.

Search `<drop behavior>` in here, 6th occurence for views 
https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can check [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) . At the bottom, in the "*External Links*" you can find The [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). Scroll down to the "*X3H2-92-154/DBL CBR-002, 11.20* " and there you can find:

```
     <drop view statement> ::=
          DROP VIEW <table name> <drop behavior>

        Note: If CASCADE is specified, then any such dependent object
        will be dropped by the execution of the <revoke statement> spec-
        ified in the General Rules of this Subclause.
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is per [SQL 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard and the syntax is

```
<drop view statement> ::=
              DROP VIEW <table name> <drop behavior>
```

> Syntax Rules
>
> 1) Let V be the table identified by the  and let VN
>       be that . The schema identified by the explicit or
>       implicit schema name of VN shall include the descriptor of V.
>
> 2) V shall be a viewed table.
>
> 3) If RESTRICT is specified, then V shall not be referenced in
>       the  of any view descriptor or the  of any assertion descriptor or constraint descriptor.
>
> ```
> Note: If CASCADE is specified, then any such dependent object
> will be dropped by the execution of the <revoke statement> spec-
> ified in the General Rules of this Subclause.
> ```
>
> Access Rules
>
> 1) The current  shall be equal to the
>        that owns the schema identified by
>       the  of the table identified by VN.
>
> General Rules
>
> 1) Let A be the current . The following
>        is effectively executed with a current  of "_SYSTEM" and without further Access
>       Rule checking:
>
> ```
>   REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON VN FROM A CASCADE
> ```
>
> 2) The identified view and its descriptor are destroyed.
>
> Leveling Rules
>
> 1) The following restrictions apply for Intermediate SQL:
>
> ```
>   None.
> ```
>
> 2) The following restrictions apply for Entry SQL in addition to
>       any Intermediate SQL restrictions:
>
> ```
> a) Conforming Entry SQL language shall not contain a <drop view
>   statement>.
> ```

Comment: I've mistakenly written CREATE instead of DROP. You may want to update your answer

Comment: Can you add a reference in the standard?

Comment: Unfortunately, belief is not fact

Comment: Nice copy and paste based on what the other 2 answers say

Comment: @gbn, NO, its an copy/paste from the direct SQL92 reference document and been posted before you actually answered. am in no need  to copy other answer ... by the time modified my original answer and posted this you commented